# Zipping two independent Flux in spring web Flux Returns Empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I was combing two flux both do independent task Asynchronously then I combine them using

```
 Flux<Tweet> tweetsByUserId = restUtils.getTweetsByUserId(userId);
    Flux<DeleteStatus> stringFlux = deleteTweets(tweetsByUserId);
    Flux<Tweet> tweetFlux = saveTweets(tweetsByUserId);
    return Flux.
            zip(stringFlux, tweetFlux)
            .map(TweetService::apply
               )
            .doOnError( e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage()))
            ;
```

Here I combine two flux and combine them to a ResponseStatus Object

```
private static ResponseStatus apply(Tuple2<DeleteStatus, Tweet> res) {
        return new ResponseStatus(res.getT2().getId(), res.getT1().deleted());
    }
```

the result was supposed to return Flux but it is returning and empty array

```
@DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public Flux<ResponseStatus> getDeleteallUserTweets(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

            return tweetService.getAndDeleteTweets(id);

    }
```

why my code is returning an empty flux instead of Flux< ResponseStatus>

Comment: What does your `deleteTweets()` and `saveTweets()` method do?

Comment: @g00glen00b both return flux of different type I combine both fluxes transforms them in to a response flux of ResponseStatus type

Comment: Add them to your question (or a simplified version that demonstrates the problem). Without it, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the zip operator just to join something. It creates 1:1 pairs of two sources, where both elements share a certain relationship. This requires both sources to have the same length. The .zip will complete when one source completes.

I assume both of your fluxes are quite independent and do not really belong together. Otherwise, you could just combine deleteTweets() and saveTweets() into one method an return a single result to apply later on.

If I wanted to delete all tweets and return a response, I would:

1. Generate a Flux<Tweet> for a given userId
2. Apply the delete operation on that flux and map each element to the individual response (responseFlux = tweetFlux.map())
3. Aggregate the responses into a result object and return it.